# Remover auto-focus do Edit_text ao colocar windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Tags: android

Eu estou colocando no meu `manifest` o atributo 
`windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` para que o `edittext` fica acima do teclado
quando ele for ativo. O problema é que ao fazer isso, o auto-focus é ativado no `edittext` assim que a `activity` é iniciada. Como posso remover esse comportamento ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_hora"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="dada" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_hora"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/oval"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:ems="4"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="dada" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/texto_notification"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/oval"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Cadastrar" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inclua a flag `stateHidden` na atribuição a [windowSoftInputMode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft):

```
<application ... >
    <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize | stateHidden" ... >
        ...
    </activity>
    ...
</application>
```

Comment: Opa, muito obrigado, funcionou aqui ! vlw vlw.